# Will ibdata1 file overwritten

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I need to check If I copy my innodb from 2 servers A and B to /var/lib/mysql of Server C.
Then what will happen to idbata1 file. Will be overwritten or it will be appended on Server C.

Answer (score 0):

That file contains the actual data, and cannot be directly merged.

First, I recommend looking into the option:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

In your my.cnf. Second, I'd consider using mysqldump to get the data into server C from one of the two other servers (after copying the files of the first one).

Comment: No we cant use per table. We are using xtrabackup for taking the backup. Is there any way we can rename ibdata file on server C and create something like servername.ibdata for other server's ibdata.

Comment: You can create two MySQL instances on Server C, but I don't think yoy can have two ibdata1 files coexist in one instance.